# The benefit of different SIP and SMTP domains?

Tags: exchange, smtp, domain, sip, lync

I was wondering if there was an advantage of having a different Lync SIP domain name from the Exchange SMTP domain name?

I could see the disadvantages, but I'm trying to understand the real world situation that I have with my current deployment.

Example:

```
SIP: [user]@itaihay.com
SMTP:[user]@marketing.itaihay.com
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real advantage to using separate (sub)domains for SIP vs e-mail...

Quite to the contrary, there is a big advantage to using the same domain, namely, each employee has a single address that can be used for either mode of contact.

person@example.com can be the employee's email address, voip contact, instant messenger contact, etc. Much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better reasons but this is why I would do it:
The main reason I would keep them separate is flexibility and isolation, to allow the migration of one service but not the other. If you decide you want a different IP address for SMTP or you want to move one of the service to a different server it may be easier to use different domains and may also reduce any effects of changes to the other service. You could also use separate firewalls and load balancers for the separate services and QoS based on IP.

Comment: SMTP will use the MX records, rather than the A record for the domain. Similarly, SIP can use NAPTR and SRV..  One can keep the services separate without using separate (sub)domains